# Problem proving $ P_{r}^{r} + P_{r}^{r+1} + ... + P_{r}^{2r} = P_{r}^{2r+1} $

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Show that $$ P_{r}^{r} + P_{r}^{r+1} + ... + P_{r}^{2r} = P_{r}^{2r+1}  $$
where r is a nonnegative integer.

This is what I've come up with so far but I'm not sure how to continue. I know I need to prove the following.

$$ r! + (r+1)!+ \frac{(r+2)!}{2!} + ... + \frac{(2r)!}{r!} = \frac{(2r+1)!}{(r+1)!}  $$

EDIT:
Applying Pascal Rule,

$$\binom{2r+1}{r+1} = \binom{2r}{r} + \binom{2r}{r+1} = \binom{2r}{r} + \binom{2r-1}{r} +\binom{2r-1}{r+1}$$

Still not clear how it will merge, pls explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: you need to show
$$
\binom{r}{0}+\binom{r+1}{1}+\cdots+\binom{2r}{r}=\binom{2r+1}{r+1}.\tag{*}
$$
This form can be proved by successive applications of the [Pascal's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) to the RHS.

---

**Edit**: (*) can be obtained by dividing both sides of
$$
r!+(r+1)!+\frac{(r+2)!}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{(2r)!}{r!}=\frac{(2r+1)!}{(r+1)!}
$$
by $r!$.

Comment: Sorry, still blur. How do I get $\binom{r}{0}$ from $r!$ and $\binom{r+1}{1}$ from $(r+1)!$

Comment: @ cozloz: please see edit.

Comment: Ah I see! But it's not clear to me why $P_{r}^r$ when divided by r! becomes $\binom{r}{0}$. Is that an identity? :)

Comment: @ cozloz: it's not a coincidence. You can perhaps read the $k$-permutations of $n$ section of: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation.

Comment: Hmm, I just read that. After reading it, I feel intuitively that $P_{r}^{r}$ should be $\binom{r}{r}$ when divided by $r!$.

Comment: If your $P_k^n$ notation means the same thing as Wikipedia's $P(n,k)$ then $P_r^r$ is just $r!$ so when you divide that by $r!$, you get $1$, which is $\binom{r}{0}$. Good luck!

Comment: Can I have  more explanation on how to use the Pascal's rule? Not sure how you got to the RHS. =)

Comment: You apply the Pascal's rule *to* the RHS. Just do it a few times then it will become clear that eventually the LHS will emerge.

Comment: I did 2 times but it doesn't seem to merge, can you explain pls, thanks!

Comment: Will select your answer again, unaccepted it temporarily so that others can explain, don't mind. :)

Comment: @ cozloz you simply need to apply it iteratively, which sets up the required series of binomial coefficients.

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Thanks, I see it.

Comment: @KimJongUn : Thanks, got it! Regarding the $P_{r}^{r}$, I'm still slightly confused. $P_{r}^{r}$ is defined as choosing r objects from a set of r objects and then permutating them which gives the r!. So when r! is divided by r!, it could be either $\binom{r}{r}$ or $\binom{r}{0}$. Right?

Comment: @cozloz that is true, however remember that the binomial coefficients are symmetrical about the middle coefficient- so $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a combinatorial argument, that should slay the problem with ease. 
A sketch of one made up on the fly:
From (2r+1) objects, r objects are selected and arranged in a row. This can be done by choosing only from r of the original (2r+1) objects, then permuting them, or choosing from (r+1) objects and permuting them etc. Adding these various permutations will naturally give the required sum as they are mutually exclusive.

Or would you prefer a more algebraic proof? An algebraic proof would rely upon division of the sum you gave by a factor of r!

$$ r! + (r+1)!+ \frac{(r+2)!}{2!} + ... + \frac{(2r)!}{r!} = \frac{(2r+1)!}{(r+1)!}  $$

This reduces the above sum to simply a sum of binomial coefficients.

Edit:

Well, going from your own working, we simply iteratively apply Pascal's rule to the remaining binomial coefficient that has the (r+1) in the lower half. Can you see that by doing so, you effectively set up a series of binomial coefficients?

Truncating it to the last application, you should get:

$\binom{2r+1}{r+1}=\binom{2r}{r}+\binom{2r-1}{r}+....+\binom{r+1}{r}+\binom{r+1}{r+1}$.

Which is the required result.

Comment: Would appreciate a combinatoric proof too but I think I have difficulty understanding the explanation you gave. I'm looking more at the algebraic proof too. Is there a way to reduce the LHS to match the RHS?

Comment: I'm still not sure how to use the Pascal's rule to match the LHS with RHS. Any hints?

Comment: @ cozloz, please refer to my original post, I have edited it in. To be succinct- you simply iteratively apply Pascal's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Divide both sides of your desired identity by $r!$ and convert to binomial coefficients to get
$$ \sum_{t=0}^r \binom{t+r}{r} = \binom{2r+1}{r+1}. $$
This is a special case of the more general identity
$$ \sum_{t=0}^n \binom{t+r}{r} = \binom{n+r+1}{r+1}, $$
which has a simple combinatorial proof: the right-hand side counts the number of subsets of $[n+r+1]$ of size $r+1$, and the left-hand side counts them by their maximal element $t+r+1$.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to use the Pascal's rule to match the LHS with RHS. Any hints? –

Comment: I haven't mentioned Pascal's rule. Rather, there is a simple combinatorial proof.